# Splitting a PDF (sub grouped pages)

Tags: bash, pdf, firefox, python-3.6

I have a PDF that was made from merged PDFs. For example, in a 21-page document, the first 5 pages are from one doc, then the next 3, then 3 more, then 4 more, 3 more, etc.

The thing of note is that each page is correctly numbered. For example when looking at the 6th page in the overall document (the 1st page of the second sub-doc), Firefox's PDF viewer says `1 (6 of 21)`. The page after that says `2 (7 of 21)`.

I am trying to "un-merge" these PDFs. How can I get that metadata page info about the PDFs and split the larger doc into its correct parts?

I've tried using PyPDF2, but when I get a page and then get a page number of that page, it doesn't get me that sub-group number
`newpageObj = pdfReader.getPage(6)`
`print(pdfReader.getPageNumber(newpageObj))`
prints "6" instead of "1"

Comment: How about using `pdftk`?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to iterate through pages with that and print their page numbers?